# If watson can return country code according to country name?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson, watson-conversation, watson-assistant

I have enabled watson assist sys-location entity, I want to get the country code when I enter country name, for example, after I entered Japan, then watson can recognize it and response JP to me, enter China then return CN, is that possible? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Watson Assistant does not return such a value by default, but you could use server actions or your app to look up those values. As an example, create a Cloud Function action to search in a list or database for the country code.

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-actions.html#dialog-actions

Answer (score 0):

No it cant be done automatically.What you can do is train Watson entity with country codes.Its better way than searching in database.